# How do I replace all punctuation in my string with "" in Python?

Tags: python, regex

If my string was:

```
Business -- way's
```

I'd like to turn this into:

```
Business  ways
```

ie. replace NON abc/123 into ""

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple regular expression:

```
import re

>>> s = "Business  -- way's"
>>> s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)
>>> s
"Business  ways"
```

Answer (score 6):

Or, if you don't want to use a regular expression for some reason:

```
''.join([x for x in foo if x.isalpha() or x.isspace()])
```

Answer (score -3):

(regular expression) replace

```
[[:punct:]]
```

with '' (if Python supports that).

[] is a character class, [::] is posix class syntax.  [:punct:] is punctuation, so the character class for all punctuation marks would be [[:punct:]]

An alternate way of the same thing is \p and friends:
\p{IsPunct}

See just below "Character Classes and other Special Escapes" in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html  (yes, I know it's a Perl document, but this is more about regular expressions than Perl).

That being said, the first answer with [^\w\s] answers what you explained a little more explicitly.  This was more just an explanation of how to do what your question asked.

Comment: python does not offer that type of pre-defined character class. The perl documentation doesn't help in this case.