# How to replace the quote " and hyphen character in a string with nothing in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to replace `"` and `-`

with `""` nothing! make it disappear.

`s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', s)` this makes all punctuation disappear, but I just want those 2 characters. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm curious as to why you are using a regular expression for this simple string replacement. The only advantage that I can see is that you can do it in one line of code instead of two, but I personally think that a replacement method is clearer than a regex for something like this.

The string object has a `replace` method - `str.replace(old, new[, count])`, so use `replace("-", "")` and `replace("\"", "")`.

Note that my syntax might be a little off - I'm still a python beginner.

Comment: Probably because it was the accepted answer to his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545655/how-do-i-replace-all-punctuation-in-my-string-with-in-python/1545678#1545678

Comment: or may be because he needs to replace multiple characters

Comment: SilentGhost, like I said, it's only two characters. To me, a regex would be more confusing when used in that situation.

Comment: And yes, it would be slower for large strings. And probably not Pythonic. If I had to remove more than 2 or 3 characters, I would use a regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub('["-]+', '', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.6/2.7, you can use the helpful `translate()` method on strings. When using `None` as the first argument, this method has the special behavior of deleting all occurences of any character in the second argument.

```
>>> s = 'No- dashes or "quotes"'
>>> s.translate(None, '"-')
'No dashes or quotes'
```

Per SilentGhost's comment, this gets to be cumbersome pretty quickly in both <2.6 and >=3.0, because you have to explicitly create a translation table.  That effort would only be worth it if you are performing this sort of operation a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub('[-"]', '', s)`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.6:

```
print 'Hey -- How are "you"?'.translate(None, '-"')
```

Returns:

```
Hey  How are you?
```